# First Steps, Linear Regression

Tags: regression

1. Suppose a simple linear regression is carried out to investigate the relationship between salary and years employed, Y and X respectively.  Given some set of data points where should one begin to carry out the regression analysis and why?  Should I begin by calculating the mean of X and Y and then developing b0 and b1?  The first step surely is to do this to create the line, right?

Comment: The first thing is to formulate the question you are trying to answer. Assuming you believe that the salary is dependent on the years of employment and not vice versa you indeed look at the `lm(Y ~ X)` model . Don't worry about "the mean", just add an intercept in your model and it will take care of that. What you care after making this regression is how your model's residuals are distributed.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  The probability distribution they follow?  Aren't they normally distributed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You would like them to normally distributed; they are not guaranteed to be.  If they are not you have to re-state your model in a way they end up being. A linear model does assume that practically $Y \sim N(X\beta,\sigma^2I)$ so you want a nice residual distribution $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ to go along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step in computing a regression (assuming that you understand the question, the assumptions, etc.) is to obtain a good statistical software program, the second step is then to learn how to use the program (if you don't have one already then R (www.r-project.org) is good and free.

The only reason to do the calculations by hand these days is to learn/get better understanding.  If that is what you are trying to do then you should use a good reference book and follow their approach (there are different versions of the formulas, each has their own advantage in helping you learn).  One set of formulas depends on the means, so calculating them is important if you follow that version.  Others don't require calculating the mean explicitly (though some of the same calculations that go into the means will be embedded inside of those calculations) and if you use those formulas then there is no need to calculate the means first.